# M2M vs Web service

Tags: web-services

What is the difference between the term Machine to Machine (M2M) communication and a Web service?

The W3C defines a Web service as

> a software system designed to support interoperable machine-to-machine interaction over a network.

Wiki defines M2M communication as a

> technologie that allow both wireless and wired systems to communicate with other devices of the same type

That sounds to me like different terms of the same thing.

SOAP, REST etc. are possibilities to implement both, Web services and M2M communication.

But what is the difference between M2M and Web service? Is it just like M2M is used in the context of an industry environment and for everything else (consumer-/financial applications) it's a Web service?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, M2M implies lower level of communication and, if I may, 'lower level' of data.

I think formal distinction comes later in the definition:

> ... It has an interface described in a machine-processable format (specifically WSDL). Other systems interact with the Web service in a manner prescribed by its description using SOAP messages, typically conveyed using HTTP with an XML serialization in conjunction with other Web-related standards.

It is a service on the Web.

So a typical web service operates over HTTP, assumes a machine-processable description and implies use of certain technologies.

M2M, on the other hand, operates over wide range of protocols, that are lower-level than HTTP, and is a subject to restrictions other than those in web services, e.g. low energy consumption, constant data feed (instead of on-demand) etc.

Also, to me web services include human component: somewhere down the road there is a person consuming the data obtained from a web service, while in the case of M2M a human consumer is less expected. A goal of M2M communication might be to sync up an array of machines or have a machine make a decision based on the data it obtained from another machine.

Answer (score 0):

Most of M2M devices rely on pure java or SIM cards to send/receive data to each others or backend systems. MNO SIM cards provide more convenient communication services with mobile data option. SIM cards provided by MNO do not come with big memory sizes and due to nature of SIM, SIM applets running on them must be minimalist.

If OTA related specifications defining remote management of SIM and SIM applications are investigated, you will see that there is always message command header and payload area as TLV byte streams(aka APDU). Each message is responded by received peer with positive or negative acknowledge. M2M applications since they mostly integrated to mobile network through SIM they also apply the same policy and defines their own raw communication protocol over SMS or TCP/IP bearer.